# Expected value of a random variable by integrating $1-CDF$ when lower limit $a\neq 0$?

Tags: probability, expected-value, cumulative-distribution-function

I have found several past answers on stack exchange ([Find expected value using CDF](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10159/find-expected-value-using-cdf)) which explains why the expected value of a random variable as such:
$$
E(X)=\int_{0}^{\infty}(1−F_X(x))\,\mathrm dx
$$
However, I am studying a partial-partial equilibrium in search theory where we have the following integral instead where a is a positive free variable:
$$
\int_{a}^{\infty}(1−F_X(x))\;\mathrm dx
$$
What would be the interpretation of this integral? Would it be correct to interpret it as some sort of conditional expectation such as $E(X | x \geq a)$. However, it seems like it is not just a conditional expectation as the value of the integral with a would be smaller than if the lower limit is just 0. Perhaps it should be some scaled version of the conditional expectation but I am unsure. Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 7):

I would like to add a thing to the answer by @Thomas Lumley

One can come up with the following:

$$\begin{align}
E[\max(X,a)]&=P(X\geq a)\cdot E[\max(X,a)|X\geq a]+P(X<a)\cdot E[\max(X,a)|X<a]\\
&=P(X\geq a)\cdot E[X|X\geq a]+P(X<a)\cdot a\\
&=P(X\geq a)\cdot E[X|X\geq a]+(1-P(X\geq a))\cdot a\\
&=P(X\geq a)\cdot (E[X|X\geq a]-a)+a
\end{align}$$

Combining this with the previous answer, we get:

$$\int_a^\infty(1-F(x))dx=E[\max(X,a)]-a=E[\max(X-a,0)]$$

**Edit:**
As @Ben added in his comment, it's with noting that in the special case $a=0$, you recover the usual expected value rule for non-negative random variables:

$$\int_0^\infty(1-F(x))dx=E[\max(X,0)]=E[X]$$

Comment: Great answer (+1).  It might be worth adding one last line noting the special case where $X$ is non-negative and $a=0$.  (In other words, the rule you state is a generalisation of the standard expectation result for non-negative random variables.)

Comment: @Ben I hadn't noticed this, thanks! I edited my answer

Answer (score 5):

There's a connection to the conditional expectation. I'll write $S_X(x)=1=F_X(x)$ for the survival function.  The conditional survival  function conditional on $X\geq a$ is
$$S_{a}(x)= \frac{P(X>a \cap X>x)}{P(X>a)}$$
which is 1 for $x<a$ and $S_X(x)/S_x(a)$ for $x\geq a$. So the conditional expectation is
$$E[X|X\geq a]=\int_0^\infty S_a(x)\,dx = \int_0^a\,dx + \frac{1}{S_x(a)}\int_a^{\infty} S_X(x)\,dx.$$

Rearranging,
$$\int_a^{\infty} S_X(x)\,dx = (E[X|X\geq a]-a)P[X>a]$$

Comment: There is a typo in the survival function formula - I couldn't correct it as StackExchange apparently requires that Edits are for a minimum of 6 characters (this is a strange criterion which means that formulas cannot be fixed by non-author).

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you got the first expression for $E[X | X \ge a]$ in terms of the integral of $S_a(x)$? And why is the integral over positive reals only? Thank you

Comment: Does this mean that $E[X | X \le a] = a - \frac{1}{F(a)} \int _{-\infty}^a F(x) dx$?

Answer (score 4):

For simplicity, consider the case where $X$ is continuous with density function $f_X$.  The standard expectation rule for non-negative random variables is derived by using integration by parts to alter the standard moment integral.  We will use the same technique here.  Using [integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) and [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) we have:

$$\begin{align}
\int \limits_{a}^\infty (1-F_X(x)) \ dx 
&= \Bigg[ x (1-F_X(x)) \Bigg]_{x=a}^{x \rightarrow \infty} + \int \limits_{a}^\infty x f_X(x) \ dx \\[6pt]
&= -a(1-F_X(a)) + \int \limits_{a}^\infty x f_X(x) \ dx \\[6pt]
&= -a + a F_X(a) + \int \limits_{a}^\infty x f_X(x) \ dx. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

We therefore have the general rule:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\max(X-a,0)] 
&= \int \limits_\mathbb{R} \max(x-a,0) f_X(x) \ dx  \\[6pt]
&= -a + \int \limits_\mathbb{R} \max(x,a) f_X(x) \ dx  \\[6pt]
&= -a + a F_X(a) + \int \limits_{a}^\infty x f_X(x) \ dx \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_{a}^\infty (1-F_X(x)) \ dx. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

In the special case where $X$ is a non-negative random variable and $a=0$ this equation reduces to the standard rule for the expectation of a non-negative random variable.  Thus, the present formula generalises that rule.