# How to compute the correlation between the min and max of two random variables?

Tags: correlation, covariance, order-statistics

A joint bivariate function (PDF) with variables $A,B$ is given in the function:

$f_{A,B}(a,b) = Cab(a+b),  \quad 0<a<1, \quad 0<b<1.$

where $C$ is just a constant. Assume that $Q=\min(A,B)$ and $R = \max(A,B).$

Compute Corr($Q,R),$ ie the correlation.

From $f(a,b)= \int_0^1\int_0^1 Cab (a+b) dxdy = 1,$ $C = 18/5.$ so that
$$f_{AB}(a,b)= \frac{18}{5} ab (a+b) da db, \ 0 < a, b < 1.$$

**UPDATE:**
\begin{align*}
f_A(a) & = 
 1/5 \ (9a^2 + 6a), \ 0 < a < 1\\
f_B(b) &= 1/5 \ (9b^2 + 6b), \ 0 < b < 1
\end{align*}
$$E(A) = 1/5 \int_0^1 a \cdot(9a^2 + 6a) da =17/20 = E(B)$$

$$E(A^2)=1/5 \int _0^1 \left(9a^4 + 6a^3\right) da = 33/50 = E(B^2)$$
\begin{align*}
1 - F_Q(q) & =  P(A >q)P(B > q)\text{ (CDF of min)}\\
& = 
\int _q^1 1/5 (9a^2 + 6a) da \cdot \int _q^1 1/5 (9b^2 + 6b) db\\
& =
\left(\frac{1}{5}(-3q^3-3q^2+6)\right)^2, & \ 0 \le q < 1
\end{align*}

The expectation and variance of $Q$ are:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(Q) & = \int_0^1  \frac{1}{5}(-3q^3-3q^2+6)dq + 
\int_1^2  \frac{1}{25}(-3q^3-3q^2+6)^2 dq =
9.85234\\
\mathbb{E}(Q^2) & = \int_0^1 \frac{2q}{5}(-3q^3-3q^2+6)dq 
+ 
\int_1^2  \frac{2q}{25}(-3q^3-3q^2+6)^2 dq = 32.9597\\
\text{Var}(Q) & = \mathbb{E}(Q^2) - (\mathbb{E}(Q))^2   \\
& =  32.9597 - (9.85234)^2 \\
& = \text{negative number; but variance is nonnegative}
\end{align*}

**I got stuck-in here because I got the variance to be negative which is wrong and I don't know where I went wrong. This is why this question is different to the other one. Thank you.**

Comment: Evidently $(A,B)$ are independent Uniform$(0,1)$ variables, right?  If so, please state that; if not, your derivation fails at the outset.  Then, please explain what this question might have to do with $f:$ it seems like $f$ is superfluous and you are just reasking a previous question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/604386.  If $f$ is intended to be a density, then this is really the same as your previous question but with a minor variation in $f$ and you can apply the techniques that were successful there.

Comment: The original question for this posted question did not say that $A$ and $B$ are independent but after obtaining their marginal PDF it suggest that they are independent.

Comment: Please, that question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/604386/correlation-between-min-and-max-of-two-different-uniform-distribution) is different to this one since it is a different function, although they may look similar but not the same question

Comment: $f$ is the joint PDF.

Comment: The only difference I see is one of computing the integrals.  Is there a new statistical question?  BTW, having equal marginals does not imply independence.

Comment: Re the edits: (1) What is "$U$"?? (2) Please graph your expression for $F_U.$  (3) The expression you give for $1-F_U$ ought to be a perfect square, because it is one expression times itself.  Your results clearly are not a perfect square.  That's an algebraic mistake.  (4) Why do you give two identical cases for that result?  One of them gives the square and the other does not.

Comment: (1) $U$ was meant to be $Q.$ (2) [Graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bjjd7pw58c) (3) I've corrected it (4) It was a mistake.

Comment: Re (2): Does that look anything like a CDF or survival function to you??

Comment: It looks completely different. That is why I am wrong:)

Comment: Yes.  If you get the CDF wrong, it's unlikely anything you calculate with it will be correct.  It's always a good idea to sketch the graph of any CDF you are working with, whether you derived it yourself or someone gave it to you.  At a minimum it will give you a sense of the basic properties of the distribution: its support, its continuity or lack thereof, its location, its spread, and perhaps a little about its skewness.

Comment: You are absolutely right.

Comment: @whuber, could you please help me to unravel this question? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this is really the same as your previous question, changing only the details, permit me to outline **a general approach to finding moments of the max and min of a bivariate random variable.**

So, generally, let $(X,Y)$ be any bivariate random variable and write $M=\max(X,Y),$ $m=\min(X,Y)$ for its extrema.  For any numbers $(i,j)$ (usually natural numbers) the (raw) $(i,j)$ moment of $(M,m)$ is

$$\mu_{i,j}(M,m) = E[M^i m^j].$$

These are relevant because correlation is a function of some of these moments.  One formula for it is

$$\rho(M,m) = \frac{\mu_{1,1}(\bar M, \bar m)}{
\sqrt{\mu_{2,0}(\bar M, \bar m)\ \mu_{0,2}(\bar M, \bar m)}}$$

where $\bar M = M - \mu_{1,0}(M,m)$ and $\bar m = m - \mu_{0,1}(M,m)$ are the centered versions of $M$ and $m.$

**The idea is to condition the calculation of the expectation according to which variable(s) $X$ and $Y$ correspond to $M$ and $m.$**  There are three possibilities:

1. When $X \gt Y,$ $X=M$ and $Y=m.$
2. When $X \lt Y,$ $X=m$ and $Y=M.$
3. When $X = Y,$ $X=Y=M=m.$

Thus, according to the basic properties of conditional expectation,

$$\begin{aligned}
\mu_{i,j}(M,m) &= E[X^i Y^j\mid X\gt Y]\Pr(X\gt Y)\\
& + E[Y^i X^j\mid X\lt Y]\Pr(X \lt Y)\\
& + E[X^{i+j}\mid X=Y]\Pr(X=Y) \\
\\
& = E[X^i Y^j\text{ and }X\gt Y] + E[Y^i X^j\text{ and }X\lt Y] +E[X^{i+j}\text{ and }X = Y].
\end{aligned}$$

When $\Pr(X=Y)=0,$ as when $(X,Y)$ has a continuous distribution, the third term drops out.

When $(X,Y)$ has a density function $f,$ it is continuous.  Fubini's Theorem usually applies and reduces the foregoing to

> $$\begin{aligned}
> &\mu_{i,j}(M,m) \\ &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty y^j \left(\int_y^\infty x^if(x,y)\mathrm dx\right)\mathrm dy + \int_{-\infty}^\infty y^i \left(\int_{-\infty}^yx^j f(x,y)\mathrm dx\right)\mathrm dy.
> \end{aligned}\tag{*}$$

---

#### Example

Suppose, as in the present question,

$$f(x,y) = C xy(x+y)\ \mathcal{I}_{[0,1]\times [0,1]}.$$

The indicator function $\mathcal I$ explicitly states the density is zero unless $0\le x \le 1$ *and* $0 \le y \le 1.$

We plug this $f$ into $(*)$ and compute

$$\begin{aligned}
\mu_{i,j}(M,m) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_y^\infty x^i y^j  C xy(x+y)\mathcal{I}_{[0,1]\times [0,1]}\,\mathrm dx\mathrm dy \\
&+ \int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^y y^i x^j  C xy(x+y)\mathcal{I}_{[0,1]\times [0,1]}\,\mathrm dx\mathrm dy\\
&= C\int_0^1 \int_y^1 x^i y^j   xy(x+y)\,\mathrm dx\mathrm dy 
+ C \int_0^1\int_{0}^y y^i x^j  xy(x+y)\,\mathrm dx\mathrm dy\\
&= C\int_0^1\left\{\int_y^1 x^{i+2}y^{j+1} + x^{i+1}y^{j+2}\,\mathrm dx+ \int_0^y x^{j+2}y^{i+1} + x^{j+1}y^{i+2}\,\mathrm dx\right\}\mathrm dy
\end{aligned}$$

**The rest is just calculations.**  For the values of $i$ and $j$ needed in the question (natural numbers), this formula involves the sum of four univariate integrals over $x.$  Just evaluate them (all four have such similar forms that you need only evaluate one and apply that result in all four cases), integrate that with respect to $y,$ and plug the answers into the formula for $\rho(M,m).$  (The constant $C$ can be found using the formula for $\mu_{0,0}.$)

Comment: My understanding is that I will need to compute $\mu_{0,1} (x=M, y=m)$ using $(*),$ then subtract it from $M,$ to obtain $\bar M.$ That is: 
\begin{aligned}
\bar M & = M-\mu_{0,1} (x=M, y=m)\\
& = x - \mu_{0,1} (x, m), \qquad (**)
\end{aligned}
(similarly for $\bar m$). Then I compute $\mu_{1,1,} (\bar M, \bar m), \ \mu_{2,0} (\bar M, \bar m), \ \mu_{0,2,} (\bar M, \bar m).$ using $(*)$ with its input arguments from $(**).$ Am I thinking right?

Comment: Yes, that is how to apply the formulas.

Comment: Not so much can be obtained from the internet about this approach. Any textual reference(s) for me to delve into it more?

Comment: Look for books on order statistics.  N. Balakrishnan is one authority.

Comment: I got the following after substituting and integrating for $\mu_{0,1}(x,m)$ but not quite sure: \begin{aligned}
\mu_{0,1} (x, m) &=  C\int_0^1\left\{ \left( \int_m^1 x^{i+2} m^{j+1} + x^{i+1}m^{j+2}\,\mathrm dx \right) + \left( \int_0^m x^{j+2} m^{i+1} + x^{j+1} m^{i+2}\,\mathrm dx \right) \right\}\mathrm dm\\
 &=  \frac{18}{5} \int_0^1\left\{ \frac{1}{3} m^{2} + \frac{1}{2} m^{3} - \frac{1}{24} m^{5} \right\}\mathrm dm \\
  &=  \frac{18}{5} \left( \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{8} - \frac{1}{24} \right)=  \frac{7}{10}. 
\end{aligned}
Then, 
$ \bar M = x - (7/10), \quad  \bar m = y - (7/10).$

Comment: Are $\bar M$ and $\bar m$ correct? I just want to make sure since the rest of the computations depend on them

Comment: I'm just checking with you to verify if my computations in the comments above are accurate?